# Tags for windows and Windows

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) is currently used to mean two completely different things:

- Manipulating windows on the GUI: [1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-swap-the-close-buttons-from-the-left-to-the-right) [2](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-disable-the-shadow-around-a-window) [3](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/314/is-there-a-way-to-split-applications-to-fit-in-elementaryos)
- Interacting with the Microsoft Windows operating system [1](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16/prepare-for-dual-booting-with-windows-8-1)

Most Stack Exchange sites where the issue comes up use `windows` for Microsoft Windows and other tag names for the GUI concept, often `window` (Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux, Super User, Emacs, Stack Overflow). Emacs and Vi use `microsoft-windows` for the operating system.

What tag names should we use here?

Answer (score 3):

From experience on sites with both `window` and `windows` as tag names, there's a lot of confusion. So let's avoid this pair.

For the operating system, [microsoft-windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-windows) is the obvious, clear alternative.

For the concept, [window-manipulation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation) and [window-decorations](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-decorations) (or [window-appearance](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-appearance)?) cover most topics (I don't expect [window-management](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-management) to be a distinct thing from [window-manipulation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation) on this site) but I don't find these to be great tag names. [gui-windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-windows) doesn't look clear to me. Better suggestions are welcome (I might steal them for U&L).

Just having a tag named `windows` is likely to cause misuse as people meaning either the concept or the OS will use the name without checking. So I propose to avoid this name altogether. It is possible to arrange for a popup to appear if someone tries to use the tag name `windows`, with a message saying something like “the name `windows` is ambiguous, use [microsoft-windows](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-windows) or [window-manipulation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-manipulation) instead”. This needs to be set up by Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: +1. I'd go for management over manipulation simply for my spelling, but it's not a big difference. I've also added [tag:microsoft-windows-8.1]. I'm not sure if we need versions, but Windows 8 is so different. Finally, what should windows be a synonym of? The Microsoft one or the GUI one?

Comment: @Tim I think `windows` should not be a synonym of either, because it has about an even chance of being the wrong one in any given instance. Please don't create version-specific tags unless there's a clear need for them, they tend to be heavily abused. A version tag should only be used on questions that don't apply to any other version, which is not the case for http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/16

Comment: Okay - yeah reading it again it's a general windows question. I've pushed your edit through, and removed the versioning details from the question itself. As this site expands, would you still recommend no verioning tags, or could they be used (I'm thinking about the difference between versions with UEFI, safe boot etc).

Comment: I second this. We need to keep an eye out for these tags though.